# How to get rid of the text that briefly shows up when a timeline plays?

Tags: javafx

I've been working on this JavaFX program and I would like to have some text ("Once Upon a Time...") fade in and out after you press a button. I got it to work using a Timeline, but every time I press the button to trigger the code, I see "Once Upon a Time..." flash briefly before disappearing, and only then does the fade in/out transition play.

```
        Label FirstText = new Label("Once Upon a Time...");
        FirstText.setVisible(false);

        FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(3000),FirstText);
        ft.setFromValue(0);
        ft.setToValue(1);
        ft.setAutoReverse(true);
                
        FadeTransition TextOut = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(3000), FirstText);
        TextOut.setFromValue(1);
        TextOut.setToValue(0);
            
        Start.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, (MouseEvent e) ->{
            scene.setFill(Color.BLACK);
            Start.setVisible(false);
           
            Timeline TextFade = new Timeline(
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, event -> ft.play()),
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(5), event -> TextOut.play())
                   
            );
            
            TextFade.play();
            FirstText.setVisible(true);
        });
```

What can I do to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: java naming conventions please

Comment: Why start different animations from a `Timeline`? A `Timeline` with 4 `KeyFrame`s that contain `KeyValue`s for the `opacity` property would achieve the same effect with just a single animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why you see what you're seeing, but there is an easier and probably more correct way to create the animation you want. It looks like the goal is to have the text fade in over three seconds, show for two *or* five seconds (depending on how I interpret your code), and then fade back out over another three seconds. This can be done with a single `FadeTransition`, a `PauseTransition`, and a `SequentialTransition`. Here's an example:

```java
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.Animation.Status;
import javafx.animation.FadeTransition;
import javafx.animation.PauseTransition;
import javafx.animation.SequentialTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class App extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    var text = new Label("Once upon a time...");
    text.setFont(Font.font(24));
    text.setOpacity(0);

    var animation = createAnimation(text);

    var button = new Button("Play animation");
    button.disableProperty().bind(animation.statusProperty().isEqualTo(Status.RUNNING));
    button.setOnAction(
        e -> {
          e.consume();
          animation.playFromStart();
        });

    var root = new BorderPane(text, button, null, null, null);
    root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
    BorderPane.setAlignment(button, Pos.CENTER);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  private Animation createAnimation(Label text) {
    var fadeTrans = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(3));
    fadeTrans.setFromValue(0);
    fadeTrans.setToValue(1);

    // Since we're auto-reversing this animation will be played
    // again immediately after it finishes. That means we set the
    // time to 2.5 seconds so that the *total* time is 5 seconds.
    // If this should actually be 2 seconds then set the time to 
    // 1 second.
    var pauseTrans = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(2.5));

    var seqTrans = new SequentialTransition(text, fadeTrans, pauseTrans);
    seqTrans.setAutoReverse(true);
    // Forwards is one cycle, the auto-reverse is the second cycle
    seqTrans.setCycleCount(2);

    return seqTrans;
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems much simpler that what I was doing, thanks!